# How to get data from a Swift NSURLSession?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

For example, I have the following code:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var dann = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        self.str = dann
})
task.resume()
```

I want to transfer the data to a variable in the class (the `str` variable in the class). The string `self.str = dann` does not convey anything. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to start this task. task.resume()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure NSString is the type you want. JSON may be format of the data returned, depending on your URL's functionality. I tried the code provided and got the same issues, but if you treat it as JSON (I used httpbin.org as a dummy URL source) and it worked.

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do{
            let str = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
            print(str)
        }
        catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

(thanks for suggested edit @sgthad. the edit is not particularly relevant to the question, but still wanted to update the code to be current.)

#### Update for Swift 3 syntax

```
let url = URL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let unwrappedData = data else { return }
    do {
        let str = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: .allowFragments)
        print(str)
    } catch {
        print("json error: \(error)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Also not work. If "println(str)" write after "task.resume()", we see nil

Comment: Correct, because of the way asynchronous tasks are executed. Because execution resumes **immediately** after `task.resume()`, `str` is nil until it has been set inside the completion handler, when the asynchronous call returns to the application.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow do it, that was not the nil, can be done synchronously?

Comment: Well, you don't want to do synchronous network calls. The network may not be readily available and your app could suffer for it. There are ways to do synchronous network calls, but I cannot, in good mind, tell you not to do it and then give you code to do it and say "but don't put this in production code."  Schedule any synchronous code to occur in the completion block (or in methods called by the completion block) after str is assigned data.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about JSON

Comment: Correct, the question doesn't explicitly state anything about JSON, but the person asking the question wanted to get the value(s) from a data object, and that is done via converting the data object to JSON. (Yes I'm assuming it is JSON-convertible, vs XML or straight data-to-string conversion. Either way, reading the comments shows the asker was also needing help with retaining said data after the async task executed).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try dispatch_async?

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {(data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           var dann = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
           self.str = dann
        })
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: shared NSURLSession calls completion blocks on main queue already

Answer (score 0):

// Swift 3 based for Quick ref.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    do{
       let str = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
       print(str)
    } catch {
        fatalError("json error: \(error)")
    }
})
task.resume()
```