# How can I Get the data from api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, url

Hi I have given a link

```
"https://joysalescript.com/api/service?ws=1"
```

and they need to get the data from that link

I don't know how to achieve that I new to this programming can anyone help me.thanks

Comment: You should read more about programming. There are may libraries available used for network call like `Alamofire` its the popular one.

Comment: @RK ios pls first check api in postman.working or not

Comment: it is not working in postman and I have given an API username and API password

Comment: @IOS what should i do with the username and password

Comment: @RKios you need to pass username and password in parameter .first pls check this link https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking . you need to know how to call get and post api

Comment: ok how can I pass the parameters @IOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from a Swift NSURLSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826904/how-to-get-data-from-a-swift-nsurlsession)

Comment: @IOS How can I parse an XML data in objective c using afnetworking??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**Simply Call and get yourData.**

-(void)getData
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://joysalescript.com/api/service?ws=1"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *data = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSError *erro = nil;

    if (data!=nil) {

        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&erro ];
//if data return type is json supposed
        if (json.count > 0) {

            for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){

                [arr addObject:[[[json[@"feed"][@"entry"] objectAtIndex:i]valueForKeyPath:@"im:image"] objectAtIndex:0][@"label"]];
           }

        }
    }
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

        [table reloadData];
    });
}];

[data resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link in Postman. It is not showing response.
My suggestion is use Alamofire for API call.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SBJson Parser to call Api

```
-(void)resetCode
{

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // getting an NSString
    NSString *id = [prefs stringForKey:@"ID"];
    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"newpassword=%@&confirmpassword=%@&id=%@",[_passwordTextField text],[_confirmPasswordTextfield text],id];
    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);


    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://joysalescript.com/api/service?ws=1"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

    // NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
        SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
        NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
        NSInteger status = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)status);
        if(status == 1)
        {

            forgotPasswordViewController *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginVC"];
            [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"yash");

        }


    }
    else {
        if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [self alertFailed:@"Login Failed!" :@"The network connection appears to be offline."];

        [hud hideAnimated:YES];



    }
}
```